# How to scroll horizontally a div to be placed in right?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have extracted the following code from a question in stackoverflow. The green box will appear to be left of the main Div when scrolling to it. Can I move to a green box, So it will be appeared in right side of the main Div?

http://jsfiddle.net/o8ngaq0e/

I tried the following function, but didn't work:

```
var $scroller = $('.scroller');
$('button').on('click', function () {       
  var divIdx = $('input').val();          
  var scrollTo = $('#d'+divIdx)     
    .css('background', '#9f3')          
    .position().right;                   
  console.log(scrollTo);
  $scroller.animate({'scrollLeft': scrollTo}, 500);    
});
```

`.position().right;` is only doing the coloring part. It is not scrolling to the box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I documented the calculations in the JS code.

**Note:** this only works for elements in the container that are not visible. So you cannot put the first element at the right side of the container.

```js
var $scroller = $('.scroller');
// assign click handler
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // get the partial id of the div to scroll to
  var divIdx = $('input').val();

  // retrieve the jquery ref to the div
  var scrollTo = $('#d' + divIdx)
    // change its bg
    .css('background', '#9f3')
    // retrieve its position relative to its parent
    .position().left;
  /*
    To position the element at the right side of the container
    subtract the width of the container and add the width
    of the element. Including the margin.
  */
  scrollTo = scrollTo - 300 + 70;
  // simply update the scroll of the scroller
  // $('.scroller').scrollLeft(scrollTo); 
  // use an animation to scroll to the destination
  $scroller
    .animate({
      'scrollLeft': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  /*important for the .position() method */
  height: 100px;
  width: 770px;
}

.container div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #39f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    <div id="d5"></div>
    <div id="d6"></div>
    <div id="d7"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
<button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="4" />
```